# How to remove such "blur" effect on css transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

There's a problem using css transitions, watch here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/vwtqhbt2/**

Using styles:

```
.hexagon-in2:hover .polygon{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    bottom: 0px;
}
.hexagon-in2 .polygon{

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

On FF and Chrome - the same effect on hover, i didn't applied any bluring effect but on hover you can see it. Any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

## ***Edit: found a better (or shorter?) solution.***

Just simply remove  `transform: rotate(30deg);` in your

```
.hexagon-in2:hover .polygon{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

so it will be like this

```
.hexagon-in2:hover .polygon{
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwtqhbt2/2/

## ***Old solution***

There is a way to remove the difference effect before and after transition. That is use `translateZ(0)`

like

```
transform: rotate(-60deg) translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* optional */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwtqhbt2/1/

but your image always blury. If you dont want that blurry, I can suggest using another CSS trick to make hexagon. Because the blur cause by the transform of your image. It got rotated several times.

In this case try to use [Triangle css trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), sizing it then put 4 triangles at the 4 corners *(you need it in the right size or else it wont look like hexagon)* . Give them high `z-index` to cover the corners of the box. Then style stuff inside.... Voila~~

[image: Prefering image]

*4 red triangles will be in these positions to simulating the hexagon*

Comment: This is a very nice one idea about triangles, will try